# How do I save my request's body as a variable?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to save my request's body as a variable on cypress, so I can use the same body for another request. How can I do it?

The code below is working, but I need to save BODY as a variable for another request. Is there a easy way to do it?

```
cy.request({
    url: "/api/affiliate/create",
    method: "POST",
    headers:
    {
        Authorization: `bearer ${access_token}`,
    },

    body: {

        "address": Random.address,
        "address_complement": Random.address_complement,
        "address_city": Random.address_city,
        "address_number": `${Random.address_number}`,
        "address_district": Random.address_district,
        "address_state": Random.address_state,
        "cep": `${Random.cep}`,
        "cnpj": Random.cnpj,
        "company_name": Random.company_name,
        "headquarters": fAffiliate.headquarters[1],
        "ie": `${Random.ie}`,
        "phone": Random.phone,
        "rntrc": `${Random.rntrc}`,
        "status": fAffiliate.status[0],
        "trading_name": Random.trading_name
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in a variable first, then use the variable in the Cypress call.

```
const body = {
  "address": Random.address,
  "address_complement": Random.address_complement,
  "address_city": Random.address_city,
  "address_number": `${Random.address_number}`,
  "address_district": Random.address_district,
  "address_state": Random.address_state,
  "cep": `${Random.cep}`,
  "cnpj": Random.cnpj,
  "company_name": Random.company_name,
  "headquarters": fAffiliate.headquarters[1],
  "ie": `${Random.ie}`,
  "phone": Random.phone,
  "rntrc": `${Random.rntrc}`,
  "status": fAffiliate.status[0],
  "trading_name": Random.trading_name
};

cy.request({
  url: "/api/affiliate/create",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `bearer ${access_token}`,
  },
  body: body
})
```

Then you can use the `body` variable again for a second request.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
In this case, i'm using faker libs to create random data. So this line "body: body" will generate exactly the same data I used on the first request or it will randomly generate new data?
Example: On the first request, the attribute "phone" was randomly generated as "X". So on the second request it will be "X" as well or it will be generate randomly?

Comment: It will use whatever is in the `body` variable, no matter how you created it.

Answer (score 1):

You may also wish to save it as a fixture, to use in more than one spec.

In /support/index.js

```js
const body = {...}
cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/request-body.json', body)
```

In the test

```js
cy.fixture('request-body.json').then(body => {
  cy.request({
    url: "/api/affiliate/create",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `bearer ${access_token}`,
    },
    body
  })
})
```